# Haskell Function for Products of Adjacent Elements in List

Tags: list, function, haskell, recursion

I am trying to create a Haskell function where the input is a list of integers, and the output is a new list of the products of adjacent elements within said list. Here is my current code:

```
productsList :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
productsList [] = []
productsList (x:[]) = []
productsList (x:y:xs) = [x * y] ++ productsList xs
```

However, when I check this in GHC, while it compiles fine, the output is wrong. For example, when I try:
`productsList [1..3]`, the output is: `[2]`, which obviously is just the product of the first two elements in the list (the correct answer here should be `[2, 6]`) To me, it seems that the possible issue may lie in that my cases are not covering when there is an x but no y, although I thought it was covered in the line `productsList (x:[]) = []`

Can anyone help me figure out what is causing this variation in output?

Comment: What is `test xs`? I assume that this is a typo for `productsList xs`.

Comment: And by the way, `[x*y] ++ test xs` is equivalent to `(x*y) : (test xs)`, which is simpler and could be a bit faster.

Comment: @bradrn You are correct. Thank you, I've edited OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s evaluate `productsList [1..3]` step by step:

```hs
productsList [1..3]
= productsList (1:2:[3])
= [1*2] ++ productsList [3]
= [1*2] ++ []
= [1*2]
```

So the issue here is that the `productsList (x:y:xs) = [x * y] ++ productsList xs` multiplies `x` and `y`, as required, but then recurses on `xs` rather than `y:xs`. This means that `productsList [a,b,c,d,e,f,…]` will calculate `[a*b,c*d,e*f,…]` rather than the required `[a*b,b*c,c*d,d*e,e*f,f*…]`. To fix this issue, you need to recurse on `y:xs` (as I briefly mentioned above) rather than just `xs`:

```hs
productsList :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
productsList [] = []
productsList (x:[]) = []
productsList (x:y:xs) = [x * y] ++ productsList (y:xs)
```

Now the function will evaluate as follows:

```hs
productsList [1..3]
= productsList (1:2:[3])
= [1*2] ++ productsList (2:[3])
= [1*2] ++ productsList (2:3:[])
= [1*2] ++ [2*3] ++ productsList (3:[])
= [1*2, 2*3] ++ []
= [1*2, 2*3]
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining it via evaluation. Being new to functional programming, it's very helpful for me to see it visually as you illustrated. I'm going to check this answer, as it is more in line with the general idea I had from my code. Thanks for the in-depth and thoughtful answer!

Comment: You’re welcome @drPepper!

Answer (score 6):

There's a fairly common idiom for this: `zip <*> tail == \xs -> zip xs (tail xs)` gives you a list of the adjacent pairs. (And because `zip` is  non-strict in its second argument, it works for empty lists as well.)

```
> zip <*> tail $ [1,2,3]
[(1,2),(2,3)]
> zip <*> tail $ []
[]
```

So your function can be defined using a simple list comprehension:

```
productsList :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
productsList xs = [x*y | (x, y) <- zip <*> tail $ xs]
```

Comment: Since I am new to Haskell (and functional programming in general), I was not aware of zip! Guess it's back to the documentation. That answer is great, thank you.

Comment: Why not simply `productsList = zipWith (*) <*> tail`, if we're going to do it the fancy way?

Comment: I played with `zipWith` and the list of pairs, but I was so hung up the pairs, that approach never occurred to me.

Comment: and in general, it seems, `map (uncurry f) . (zip <*> g) == zipWith f <*> g`.